# Write a value to an indiviual CSV file index in Python

Tags: python, csv, integer, row, writer

I've been messing around with reading csv files lately and now I want to rewrite a single value to a row from an integer defined in python. Heres my reading code;

```
n=random.randint(0, 20)
cr = csv.reader(open('E:/file.csv', 'r'))
for row in cr:
     labelNUMBER.config(text = row[n])
```

My writing code;

```
newnumber = 2
crwrite = csv.writer(open('E:/file.csv', 'r+'))
crwrite.writerow(n[newnumber])
```

This obviously doesn't work. But I want to write a row in a csv file which is essentially

```
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

and make it

```
 1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1
```

given that my random number, n, equals 3.

If there is a way to rewrite a single value this way I'd love some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this look right?

You have to give the whole row to the writer.  Also note that when using the `csv` module you should open the file in binary mode, `"rb"`.

```
element_to_modify_idx = 2
reader = csv.reader(open("infile.csv", "rb"))
writer = csv.writer(open("outfile.csv", "wb"))
for row in reader:
    # modify desired element in row
    row[element_to_modify_idx] = "fancy new value"
    writer.writerow(row)
```